# Conectar Asterisk con AGI y pasar valores de AGI a Asterisk

Tags: perl, asterisk

Hola buenos días estoy trabajando con Asterisk v 1.4 y AGI, en el archivo AGI estoy trabajando con Perl donde tengo el siguiente código:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use POSIX;
use Asterisk::AGI;

$valor = 8;

%MYSQL = (
hostname => "localhost",
username => "root",
password => "xxx",
database => "xxx"
);

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$MYSQL{database}:$MYSQL{hostname}","$MYSQL{username}","$MYSQL{password}")or die("No se hiso la conexion!\n");
my $get_rows = "SELECT calldate from cdr limit 1";
my $rows_r = $dbh->prepare($get_rows);
$rows_r->execute();

$dbh->disconnect;

my $AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;
$AGI->set_variable("result", $valor);
```

Lo ejecuto y no marca ningún error y me retorna el 8, hasta aquí todo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Asterisk tengo el siguiente código donde mando llamar a ese archivo AGI :

```
exten => 0444423117XX,1,AGI(limit_ldi.agi)
exten => 0444423117XX,2,NoOp(${result})
exten => 0444423117XX,3,Set(GLOBAL(Count_Min)=${result})
exten => 0444423117XX,4,GotoIf($[${Count_Min} > 10 ]?203)
exten => 0444423117XX,5,Macro(dialldicve_time|SIP/TRK-4421612608|${EXTEN}|${CONTEXT})
exten => 0444423117XX,203,NoOp(NO HAY SALDO)
exten => 0444423117XX,204,Set(DIALSTATUS=CHANUNAVAIL)
```

Y yo pensando que voy a obtener el valor 8 de AGI en Asterisk me manda el siguiente error y no obtengo el 8, manda vacío al imprimir result en NoOp.

```
AGI Script limit_ldi.agi completed, returning 0
 -- Executing [0444423117XXX@prodar:2] NoOp("SIP/prodar-171-00000109", "") in new stack
 -- Executing [0444423117XXX@prodar:3] Set("SIP/prodar-171-00000109", "GLOBAL(Count_Min)=") in new stack
 == Setting global variable 'Count_Min' to ''
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

Comment: dos cosas: si ejecutas tu script sin invocar el interprete de perl, funciona? es decir solo con ./limit_ldi.agi si sí, el propietario del script es el mismo que el usuario bajo el que corre asterisk? checa esas dos cosas.

Comment: Como indica Nizhi, el script debe tener el permiso de ejecucion. Ya que veo que ejecutaste el script indicando el interprete, pero para que Asterisk lo ejecute debe tener permisos de ejecucion. Revisa esa parte

Answer (score 0):

El Agi retorna 0 de que completo la tarea.
No podras obtener una respuesta. Lo que debes hacer es enviar a gotoif dentro de tu plan de marcado.